# i write the below code , how can i cleaning it? can any one help me to write it better?

Tags: php, laravel, code-cleanup

I write this code in laravel any one can help me to write it better ?

```
 Setting::where('key' , 'online_course')->update(['value' => $request->get('online_course') ]);
    Setting::where('key' , 'read_item')->update(['value' => $request->get('read_item') ]);
    Setting::where('key' , 'comment_item')->update(['value' => $request->get('comment_item') ]);
    Setting::where('key' , 'rate_item')->update(['value' => $request->get('rate_item') ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your idea i write this code

```
foreach ($request->except('_token' , '_method') as $key => $value){
        Setting::where('key' , $key)->update(['value' => $value]);
    }
```

but this code working correctly

```
 foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value){
        Setting::where('key' , $key)->update(['value' => $value]);
    }
```

Comment: Which is what I suggested?

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution would be to use a `foreach` loop pulling your `keys` and `values` from the `$request` object:

```php
foreach ($request->only('online_course', 'read_item', 'comment_item', 'rate_item') as $key => $value) {
    Setting::where('key', $key)->update(['value', $value]);
}
```

You **could** use `$request->all()` to grab all the `keys` from the `$request` object to shorten it further but if you were to do that, ensure that you have sufficient valudation and safe guards in place (such as mass assignment) so that you don't accidentally use some unwanted `$request` data.